# glibc - #define void

Tags: c, glibc, libc

I started to look into glibc ([GNU Libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/))
to understand how it's written. In `malloc.c`, I found a piece of code as follow:

```
#ifndef void
#define void        void
#endif
```

Can someone please explain to me what this means? Isn't `void` always defined?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at [the git history](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commitdiff;h=22a891871), it was like this:

```
/*
  Void_t* is the pointer type that malloc should say it returns
*/

#ifndef Void_t
#if (__STD_C || defined(WIN32))
#define Void_t      void
#else
#define Void_t      char
#endif
#endif /*Void_t*/
```

This was a workaround for historical [C], which did not have `void` and `malloc()` returned `char *` instead of `void`.  The code was removed by Ulrich Drepper in 2011.  The commit does not seems to be generated by a script or anything automatic, so he must had his intension to define like that.

The commit message does not say anything about `void`:

> Simplify malloc code
>
> Remove all kinds of unused configuration options and dead code.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It was very helpful. I saw the removal of the above code and all the changes from `Void_t` to `void`, but `#define void void` still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: It doesn't to me, neither. I've checked glibc code to see if there is `#ifdef void` to do a conditional compilation, but I couldn't find any. It might be better to just ask him or on the glibc mailing list.  But I don't know.

Comment: I’m extremely certain this is just a botched part of the refactoring and can just be removed.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know for certain what the reason for the `#define void void` is in `malloc.c`, but my guess follows:

As [Yasushi Shoji mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11980324/12711), `void` was not always a keyword in C.  When it was introduced/standardized, a common workaround to be able to compile code using the new `void` keyword with compilers that didn't support it was to define `void` as a macro such as:

```
#define void int   /* or maybe #define void char */
```

that macro definition might be done using the compiler command line instead of via a header so that there wouldn't be a need to ensure that all the translation units included a header that defined the macro.

However, it might also be common for programmers migrating to the new keyword to use sequences of code that looked like:

```
#ifndef void
#define void int
#endif
```

for example, you'll see the following bit of code:

```
/*
 * This is a fairly bogus thing to do, but there seems to be no better way for
 * compilers that don't understand void pointers.
 */
#ifndef void
#define void char
#endif
```

in http://buildbot.zope.org/Squid-2.4STABLE6%2B/include/snmp_impl.h?annotate=1.1.1.1&cvsroot=Zope.org

So, my guess is that the `#define void void` in `malloc.c` is just a way to prevent any such sequences that might exist in the headers it includes from redefining `void`, yet still allow it to have been previously defined 'gloablly' (there are only comments in `malloc.c` before the `#define void void`) in case it was being compiled on a configuration that didn't support `void`.  In other words, if `void` wasn't globally defined as a macro before when `malloc.c` was started to be compiled, there was no reason something should define to be something else later on in the compile.

Answer (score 4):

Although `void` is a keyword in C, keywords are not defined as preprocessor symbols. The code you quoted ensures that it is also defined as a preprocessor symbol.

I don't know why this would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`void` may always have a meaning, but I'd say void *isn't* normally `#define`d. I don't know *exactly* what's going on there, but the consequence of this run of code is that if anyone says `#ifdef void` later on, it'll be true. So in other words, it'll only get `#define`d to `void` once by this run of code.